# Verb Tenses: Present Perfect vs. Present Perfect Progressive

Tags: verbs, tenses, present-perfect, progressive-aspect

Please answer and explain this:

"David could help, as he **(has been serving/has served)** as an ambassador for the last seven years and won't retire until 2010."

According to the book that i'm using, the correct answer is **"has served"**. My initial answer was **"has been serving"** since the sentence tells us that David was and still an ambassador (something that started in the past and continued until now) MOREOVER there is a duration of the action - **"for the last seven years"**. To my knowledge, if there is a duration the form of present perfect continuous should be used, which is **"has been serving"**. I'm confused. Please explain it further. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is difference between present perfect and present perfect continuous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/486557/what-is-difference-between-present-perfect-and-present-perfect-continuous)

Answer (score 2):

"Has served" is the **present perfect,** whereas "has been serving" is the **present perfect *continuous.***  Let's look at the differences between the two.

In this case, the *present perfect* and the *present perfect continuous* describe an event that has started in the past and is still happening.

Although the continuous tense usually puts more emphasis on the activity itself, "sometimes we can use either form and the meaning is the same [[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-simple-or-present-perfect-continuous)]:"

> I’ve lived here for 20 years.

> I’ve been living here for 20 years.

The above two sentences are *very similar* to the one that you wrote.

It is really **the author's choice** in the sentence you provided.  If the author chooses the continuous form, it puts a little more emphasis on the *duration* of David's service as an ambassador.

*If the author wants to emphasize that David's been serving for 7 years, they should use the present perfect continuous tense.  If they want to emphasize the fact that he isn't going to retire until 2010, then they should use the (simple) present perfect tense.*

---

Note: there *are* other uses for these two tenses, but this answer only covers the uses that the OP used.

Comment: I prefer this answer to that at the duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you!